# Reply to email with customized contents, while keeping the email trail, run-time error '287'

Tags: excel, vba, email, outlook

I want to search for an email, reply with contents specified in the code, `strHTML`, while keeping the previous email trail, `latestEmail.HTMLBody`.

I couldn't make both happen at the same time.
If I include the specified reply contents, then I lose the previous conversation; otherwise, I can keep the previous conversation but fail to incorporate the specified reply contents.

If I don't include the command `.HTMLBody = strHTML & latestEmail.HTMLBody` then the reply email will include the previous email conversation but I won't have the reply content that I want to include in the email.

If I use the above command I get

> run-time error '287' application-defined or object-defined error

If I use `.HTMLBody = strHTML` the code I will lose the email track.

```vb
'set the subject to serach for
SubjectToSearch = ShEmail.range("b3").Value

'to get the inbox folder
Set outlookapp = CreateObject("outlook.application")
Set outlooknamespace = outlookapp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set inboxfolder = outlooknamespace.GetDefaultFolder(6)

Set mailitems = inboxfolder.Items

'sort the emails
mailitems.Sort "ReceivedTime", True

'initialize variables
latestreceivedtiem = DateSerial(2023, 1, 1)

For Each mailitem In mailitems

    If mailitem.Subject = SubjectToSearch Then
        'check if the current email is the latest one
        If mailitem.ReceivedTime > latestreceivedtime Then
            Set latestEmail = mailitem
            
            latestreceivedtime = mailitem.ReceivedTime
            foundEmail = True
        End If
    End If
    
Next mailitem

If foundEmail Then
    Dim ReplyEmail As Object
    Set ReplyEmail = latestEmail.Reply

    With ReplyEmail
        .To = ShEmail.range("B1")
        .CC = ShEmail.range("B2")
        .Subject = "Re: " & latestEmail.Subject

        .HTMLBody = strHTML & latestEmail.HTMLBody
        .Attachments.Add AttachmentPath1
        
        .display
    End With
Else
    MsgBox "no emails found with the subject:" & SubjectToSearch, vbInformation
    
End If
```

I tried `.body` instead of `.HTMLbody`, but that doesn't work either.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76479117/edit) the post to put in code that reproduces the behaviour described. [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Cannot reproduce. It may be as simple as replacing `.htmlbody = strHTML & latestEmail.htmlbody` with the normal `.htmlbody = strHTML & .htmlbody`.

Comment: Thanks Niton, I tried this line ".htmlbody = strHTML & .htmlbody", it still won't work. Somehow I feel the vba just doesn't like the strHTML and .htmlbody in the sameline.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). As well indicate what is in `strHTML`.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot concatenate 2 HTML strings and expect a valid HTML string back - the two must be merged: search the HTML for `"<body"`, find the next `">"` (that takes care of the body tags with attributes), then insert you HTML after that `">"`.

Also, do not loop through all items in a folder - use [Items.Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.find)/`FindNext` or [Items.Restrict](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.restrict).

Not that it matters much in light of the above, but after finding the match, exit the loop instead of continuing it - you already have the collection sorted in the right order.

Comment: I agree, 2 HTML strings can not be concatenated directly. I tried the below code, search the body and try to insert,

Comment: Function getHtmlBody(email As Object) As String

    Dim htmlbody As String
    
    On Error Resume Next
    
    htmlbody = email.htmlbody
        
    On Error GoTo 0
        
    getHtmlBody = htmlbody
            
End Function

Comment: Function InsertHTMLAfterBody(htmlbody As String, strHtml As String) As String
    Dim bodyStartpos As Long
    bodyStartpos = InStr(1, htmlbody, "<body>", vbTextCompare)
        
        If bodyStartpos = 0 Then
        
            InsertHTMLAfterBody = htmlbody & vbCrLf & "<br>" & strHtml
        Else
            InsertHTMLAfterBody = Left(htmlbody, bodyStartpos + 5) & vbCrLf & "<br>" & strHtml & Mid(existingBody, bodyStartpos + 6)
        End If

End Function

Comment: and change the main code to                                                                                      
 With ReplyEmail
        
'        ReplyEmail.SentOnBehalfOfName = "sender@example.com"
        .To = ShEmail.range("B1")
        .CC = ShEmail.range("B2")
        .Subject = "Re: " & latestEmail.Subject
        'concatente strHTML with the existing HTMLBody
        Dim existingBody As String
        
        
        existingBody = getHtmlBody(latestEmail)
       
       .htmlbody = InsertHTMLAfterBody(existingBody, strHtml)
        
        .display
      End With

Comment: I don't get the error now, but the previous email thread still lost, do you have any recommendations?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "previous email thread still lost"? Do you mean the original message in the body of the email? Or the message position in the conversation thread?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Regarding previous email thread, I mean the original message in the body of the email, so people can see the conversation history.

Comment: I realized one thing, my code doesn't run is probably caused by the way I reference the original message in the body of the email is incorrect. As when I set Set ReplyEmail = latestEmail.ReplyAll and display the email, I can see all history of the conversation is defaulted there, however if  I go to reference ReplyEmail .HTMLBody=latestEmail.HTMLbody, even I didnt concatenated the strHTML, I still get the error 287. So any idea why "ReplyEmail .HTMLBody=latestEmail.HTMLbody" isn't working, since i can see latestEmail is referenced correctly?

Comment: Have you tried to output/log the exact HTML that causes error 287?

Answer (score 0):

> run-time error '287' application-defined or object-defined error

You get an error at runtime because the code may handle only mail item instances in the code. Be aware, Outlook folders may contain different item types - documents, appointments, notes and etc. So, before accessing item-specific properties you need to make sure that you deal with a mail item by checking the type name:

```
 If TypeOf objItem Is MailItem Then
      Set objMailItem = objFolder.Items(i)
```

or

```
If TypeName(Item) = "MailItem" Then
    Set oItem = Item
```

Second, iterating over all items in the folder is not really good idea:

```
For Each mailitem In mailitems

    If mailitem.Subject = SubjectToSearch Then
        'check if the current email is the latest one
        If mailitem.ReceivedTime > latestreceivedtime Then
```

Instead, you need to use the `Find`/`FindNext` or `Restrict` method of the `Items` class where you could get only items that correspond to the search criteria. Read more about these methods in the articles that I wrote for the technical blog:

- [How To: Use Find and FindNext methods to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder (C#, VB.NET)](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/20/outlook-find-findnext-retrieve-mail/)
- [How To: Use Restrict method to retrieve Outlook mail items from a folder](https://www.add-in-express.com/creating-addins-blog/2011/09/23/outlook-restrict-method-retrieve-mail/)

Multiple search criteria can be combined into a single search string by using the logical operators like AND, OR etc.

For example, to filter items by the keyword in the subject string:

```
criteria = "@SQL=" & Chr(34) _ 
& "urn:schemas:httpmail:subject" & Chr(34) _ 
& " like '%question%'"
```

To filter items by the received time you can use the following code:

```
'All three filters shown below will return the same results 
    'This filter uses DASL date macro for today 
    strFilter = "%today(" _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") & ")%" 
     
    'or

    'This filter uses urn:schemas:httpmail namespace 
    strFilter = AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " > '" & datStartUTC & "' AND " _ 
    & AddQuotes("urn:schemas:httpmail:datereceived") _ 
    & " < '" & datEndUTC & "'"
```

where

```
Public Function AddQuotes(ByVal SchemaName As String) As String 
    On Error Resume Next 
    AddQuotes = Chr(34) & SchemaName & Chr(34) 
End Function
```

Finally, you need to deal with a well formed HTML markup. Even when Outlook in most cases handles improperly formatted HTML documents, you need to make sure that your code deal with a properly formatted well-formed HTML markup. See https://www.developer.com/languages/xml/well-formed-html/ for more information.